# How to delete a specific slide from bootstrap carousel using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.
Basically in my Carousel, in some slides I have the Decline button, on clicking of which I want to delete/remove that slide and navigate to the next slide.
Is it possible using JQuery?
I was trying something similar here in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nqddjpa/1/)

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel'),
    $carouselItems = $('.item', $carousel);

$carousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $carouselItems.removeClass('prev next');
    var $active = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $active.next().addClass('next');
    $active.prev().addClass('prev');
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
         $("#li1").remove();
        $("#li2").attr("data-slide-to",0);
         $("#li2").attr("data-slide-to",1);
         $("#div2").addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/2nqddjpa/1/

Comment: you want to delete the active slide on the fly ?

Comment: Correct! and make the next one as Active!And this Deletion is to be done on click of a button which resides in the same active form(which is to be deleted)!

Comment: Does anyone has any clue?Or is it impossible through JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On button Click get the active slide and remove it from the DOM. Now make the next `.item` element active

JS

```js
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
$("button").click(function() {
  currentIndex = $('div.active').index();
  var ActiveElement = $carousel.find('.item.active');
  ActiveElement.remove();
  var NextElement = $carousel.find('.item').first();
  NextElement.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.content-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-area">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="li1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="li2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="li3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" id="div1">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/960/600">
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="div2">
                <img src="http://placebear.com/960/600">
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="div3">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/960/600">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>

</div>
<div>
    <button>Remove div element</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to write code for updating Carousel Indicators on removing element from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant.  I was trying to do this and managed to freeze the carousel.  Your code works great.  Only thing of note is that there appears to be an unused line of code i.e :
currentIndex = $('div.active').index();
currentIndex variable does not appear to be used.